# Merging/Joining 2 array objects on attribute in lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Is it possible to merge two array object based on an attribute present in both arrays.

I would like to achieve this via lodash lib.

eg Consider a list of catogories with id as PK and a list of movies with catagoryId as a FK

Array of movie category:

```
[{
    id: "cartoon",
    catagoryName:"Cartoon", 
},{
    id: "drama",
    catagoryName:"Drama",   
},{
    id: "action",
    catagoryName:"Action",  
}]
```

Array of movies.

```
[{
    categoryId:"action",
    movieName:"Spy",
    year: 2015
},{
    categoryId:"drama",
    movieName:"San Andreas",
    year: 2015
},{
    categoryId:"cartoon",
    movieName:"Rio",
    year: 2013
},{
    categoryId:"action",
    movieName:"Jurassic World",
    year: 2015
}]
```

The output that that i am looking for via underscore or lodash.

```
[{
    id: "cartoon",
    catagoryName:"Cartoon",
    movies:[{
        categoryId:"cartoon",
        movieName:"Rio",
        year: 2013
    }]
},{
    id: "drama",
    catagoryName:"Drama",   
    movies:[{
        categoryId:"drama",
        movieName:"San Andreas",
        year: 2015
    }]
},{
    id: "action",
    catagoryName:"Action",
    movies:[{
        categoryId:"action",
        movieName:"Jurassic World",
        year: 2015
    },{
        categoryId:"action",
        movieName:"Spy",
        year: 2015
    }]  
}]
```

I know i can do this with for loop but wanted to know if there is a better cleaner way.

Any suggestions can help. This is node js applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `groupBy` to group the movies by their category, and then `map`ed the categories by extending them with the proper list of movies.

```
groupedMovies = _.groupBy(movies, 'categoryId');

_.map(categories, function(cat) {
  return _.extend({movies: groupedMovies[cat.id] || []}, cat);
})
```

```js
var categories =
[{
    id: "cartoon",
    catagoryName:"Cartoon",
},{
    id: "drama",
    catagoryName:"Drama",
},{
    id: "action",
    catagoryName:"Action",
}];

var movies =
[{
    categoryId:"action",
    movieName:"Spy",
    year: 2015
},{
    categoryId:"drama",
    movieName:"San Andreas",
    year: 2015
},{
    categoryId:"cartoon",
    movieName:"Rio",
    year: 2013
},{
    categoryId:"action",
    movieName:"Jurassic World",
    year: 2015
}];

groupedMovies = _.groupBy(movies, 'categoryId');
_.map(categories, function(cat) {
  return _.extend({movies: groupedMovies[cat.id] || []}, cat);
})

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(groupedMovies, null, 2) + "</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note: This leaves both `categories` and `movies` unchanged.

Comment: This answer is mostly there.  Each category doesn't have a `cat.id`. You need to take the lowercase value of `cat.categoryName`.

Comment: @JoseM I'm not sure I follow.  As far as I can tell, every category _does_ have an `id`.

Comment: @JoseM I added a snippet so you can see that it works.

Comment: you are right, I totally missed that property, doh!